# Unity3D rotate GameObject to face direction of travel

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry, gameobject

I am creating a program using Unity3D in which the player fires an arrow at a target. What is the best way to ensure that the arrow is flying through the air at a rotation which depends on it's angle of movement? (ie the arrow head is facing upward of ascent and downward on descent)

I've had a look at the **transform.LookAt** and **Quaternion.lookRotation** functions I'm but now sure how they can apply. Here's the code which dictates the arrows velocity:

```
            newArrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3 (5*(transform.position.x - mousePos.x), 10*(transform.position.y - mousePos.y), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints on the rigidbody. In your case it should only rotate around the x axis so that it aims up and then down.

For the rest, you just set the initial rotation on throw:

```
newArrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(velocity);
```

This may need some tweak based on your model initial orientation.

Comment: I don't think any constraints are needed. `velocity` should be enough to make sure the arrow points into the right direction. Also, rotation must be updated per frame, because velocity will change its direction over time.

Comment: There is a high chance of model starting to rotate if you do not set constraint. This is due to the fact that the rigidbody on the model is not exactly acting as a real arrow, you would have to set one on the front, one on the body and one on the back. Same for the mass of each part of the arrow. If you add one rigidbody for the whole model, then it will most likely behave unexpectedly. The constraints are there in this case to fake reality at lower cost. You still have to update the arrow x rotation based on velocity so that it points upward and then downward following the arc shape.

Comment: Very true indeed, I forgot about the fact that there is a Rigidbody that would meddle with the rotation of the object. Nice shot! Of course you would only set rotation contraints, not movement, right?